# CSS div position/size within table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, cell

I have an unusual problem.

I am needing to position a div (which I have full CSS control over) inside a table cell (which I do not).  The lack of control is due to a 3rd party framework containing my content.

Ideally I would like to both align the div to the top of the table cell (currently aligns to centre) and have the height of the div be 100% of the table cell at all times (even if text in other cells mean the row expands vertically).

Normally for valign I would us relative/absolute positioning but this time I have no way to add "position:relative" to the parent cell.

Any ideas would be most welcome.

```
<table>
<tr><td><div style="">Entry Fee:</div></td>
<td><div style="">Adults £12.00<br />Juniors £10.00</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle to show us what you mean?

Comment: Why you have to use divs? i mean, seams like you're just adding text, couldn't you add just the text without divs directly inside the tds?

Comment: This is a job for..... jQuery!!! able to leap your code in bounds, faster than... a ugly written js function.. More powerful than mootools.. Its jQuery!

Comment: I have to use divs because that is the only element I can style using non-inline css, it's a silly effect of the cms being used.

Comment: There is no access to jQuery or any other 3rd party tools

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this CSS to your div:

```
td div {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: That DOESNT work.  Height is still height of text contained within the div